# Adjust the Layout when AdMob Banner get Displayed

Tags: android, layout, admob

I am integrating **AdMob Banner** ad in my `Activity`. The layout consist of a `GridView` and `AdView`.

**What I Want:-**

When ad is not shown, i.e. at start or when ad is getting downloaded or anything, I want the `GridView` to have all the screen. But when ad is to be displayed, it should cover required space below but do not overlap anything.

**My Layout:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/ll_gridmain"
    tools:context="mohits.app.picreddit.itemgrid">

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:background="#454545" >
    </GridView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/banner_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="gone">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Activity:-**

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("xxx")
        .build();
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

**What I am Getting:-**

The `banner_view` layout is always showing even if I am setting it to `GONE`. This should only become visible when the ad is to be shown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is even if you remove your banner, the weight of the `GridView` will still be `9` and the `weightSum` of the layout is `10`, so the `GridView` will not fill the whole `LinearLayout`.

Removing the following line from your layout should work:

```
android:weightSum="10"
```

Also, setting the visibility of the `AdView` is redundant.

Setting the visibility of a `ViewGroup` will also affect their children.

You could remove the following attribute from your `AdView`:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

After that, setting the visibility of `banner_view` should be enough:

```
@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    super.onAdLoaded();
    bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```